# webkit filter to gradient

Tags: css, webkit, gradient

I have the css

```css
.filter-gradient.green:after{
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(52,143,80,1) 0%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(52,143,80,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(52,143,80,1) 0%,rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(52,143,80,1) 0%,rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(52,143,80,1) 0%,rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  rgba(52,143,80,1) 0%,rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#348f50', endColorstr='#de56b4d3',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */

}
```

But I need change gradient to webkit-filter sephia, grayscale, hotate, invert, blur, saturate, contrast...
I can't change the gradient to webkit-filter, why?
Can anyone help me or explain a method ?

Thanks

Comment: If the answer given doesn't help you out, please create a jsfiddle showing the problem and maybe we can be more helpful.

Comment: I use the demo: http://demos.creative-tim.com/landing-page
The side left show adjustments of color.
I want add one webkit-filter with grayscale, blur, sephia, hotate and invert.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo-element is lacking the `content` property and any dimensions...otherwise it seems to work fine.

```css
.filter-gradient.green {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.filter-gradient.green:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(52, 143, 80, 1) 0%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(52, 143, 80, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(52, 143, 80, 1) 0%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(52, 143, 80, 1) 0%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(52, 143, 80, 1) 0%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(52, 143, 80, 1) 0%, rgba(86, 211, 146, 0.75) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(150deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-gradient green"></div>
```

Comment: Paulie_D, your solve is better.
But it has low precision on the colors webkit-filter.
Exemple is possible look the color originals beneath layer webkit-filter grayscale, sepia and others filters.
This my demo http://demos.creative-tim.com/landing-page, the side right have the tables adjustments fo colors to gradient.
I want replace gradient to webkit-filter.
Thanks very much by help.

Comment: Frankly it's not clear to me what you are trying to do. you can't apply filters to background image....only elements.

Comment: I understand.
Your solution help me.
Thanks very much!